# generating images using for loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, imshow

I made a program that generates an image consiting of concentric rings whose value is given by a random number:

```
cx=20;cy=20;ix=40;iy=40;
[x,y]=meshgrid(-(cx-1):(ix-cx),-(cy-1):(iy-cy));  
a=zeros(40,40);
x1=rand(1,20);

for j= 1:20
%%inner radius
R=j-1;
c1=((x.^2+y.^2)<=R^2);
n1=not(c1);
%%outer radius
R=j;
c2=((x.^2+y.^2)<=R^2);
rj=bitand(c2,n1);
rj=rj.*x1(1,j);
a=imadd(a,rj);
end
imshow(a)
```

The problem is that I want to get consecutive images as if the rigns were moving orderly. So I employed the circshift function and my code is now something like:

```
cx=20;cy=20;ix=40;iy=40;
[x,y]=meshgrid(-(cx-1):(ix-cx),-(cy-1):(iy-cy));  
a=zeros(40,40);
x1=rand(1,20);
for i= 1:20
xc=circshift(x1,[1 i-1]);
%%inner radius
R=j-1;
c1=((x.^2+y.^2)<=R^2);
n1=not(c1);
%%outer radius
R=j;
c2=((x.^2+y.^2)<=R^2);
rj=bitand(c2,n1);
rj=rj.*xc(1,j);
a=imadd(a,rj);
end
imshow(a)
```

and the program doesn't run. Can anyone help me please? Best regards.

Comment: Please include the error you are getting in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over 'i' whereas in your loop you use both i and j, as in your previous code, which Matlab does not recognize and may interpret as being the imaginary unit. Anyhow using all j works fine; I modified your code a little so we can see the circle growing:

```
clear all
clc
close all

cx=20;cy=20;ix=40;iy=40;

[x,y]=meshgrid(-(cx-1):(ix-cx),-(cy-1):(iy-cy));
a=zeros(40,40);
x1=rand(1,20);

for j= 1:20
    xc=circshift(x1,[1 j-1]);
    %%inner radius
    R=j-1;
    c1=((x.^2+y.^2)<=R^2);
    n1=not(c1);
    %%outer radius
    R=j;
    c2=((x.^2+y.^2)<=R^2);
    rj=bitand(c2,n1);
    rj=rj.*xc(1,j);
    a=imadd(a,rj);

    imshow(a) % Put imshow in the loop
    pause(0.05) % little pause (0.05 seconds)
end
```

Comment: @Carolina Rickenstorff so did it help?